# Перестал работать виджет Posts плагина Elementor Pro после переноса сайта на другой хостинг

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины, elementor

Мастерил клиенту сайт на своём хостинге, всё работало без проблем. После переноса сайта, учитывая все правила грамотного экспорта с базой данных и тд. и тп. на хостинг клиента, перестал работать исключительно виджет Posts. Пропали все элементы данного виджета во внешнем виде сайта, а в настройках самого виджета - пустой раздел Layout (см на фото).

Несколько раз переустановил плагин, очистил кэш, попробовал импортировать Posts со старого сайта как шаблон, но при этом получил ошибку импорта.

Прошу помочь, сроки сильно поджимают!!!

Ниже фото для сравнения, 1 - новый хостинг, 2 - старый хостинг

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ищите ошибки в консоли, в логах и тп.

Comment: "Грамотный экспорт" - это какой?

Comment: @SeVlad элемент красивого предложения, не вдавайтесь в подробности)), имел ввиду перенёс сайт как это объясняют специалисты на youtube

Comment: @Simon везде всё чисто, без единого намёка на ошибку. Это оказывается распространённая проблема. Во многих пабликах открывали этот вопрос, но так ответа и не нашлось.

Comment: @Sanjar это не "элемент", а ключевой момент. А ты даже не  в курсе о чем я тебя спросил :(. Не смотри ютубо-"специалистов", читай правильных специалистов https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/767562